# Link to Ionic page from external website

Tags: hyperlink, ionic-framework

I'm integrating an Ionic app with a 3rd party web authentication framework. The framework requires that the user visit a web page to authenticate and then receive several authentication token cookies.

I plan to open a link to the external login page, have the user authenticate, and then be redirected back to the Ionic app.

I need a URL to the homepage of my app so that the login page can redirect the user back after logging in. How do I generate a a URL for a location in the Ionic app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just use the in app browsers plugin so that the user never has to leave the app in the first place.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Our app has a blog and we use this

```
   $scope.readMore = function (index) {
        $scope.link = $scope.articles[index].WebLink;
        window.open($scope.link, '_blank', 'transitionstyle=crossdissolve,toolbarposition=top');
    };
```

by using the option _blank we can have the user open up a webpage inside the app not have to have the navigate away from the app in order to access a url, i also looks way better than a iframe.

Comment: What to do if opening external URL in webview only?? and if we want to come to back to angular state?? with data possibly?